# Create separate SHA-1 Key for same package ID in Firebase

Tags: android, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I've created 2 different firebase projects.  One for development and one for production (myProjectDev, and myProject).  I've also created an app with Ionic that runs on both ios and android platforms.

I want to use the same bundle/package ID for both firebase projects because if I change the bundle/package ID then I'm forced to setup an entirely separate app in TestFlight/Google play store.  I feel like I shouldn't have to do that but then again I'm new to a lot of this.

So with that being said I'm trying to figure out how to generate 2 different SHA-1 keys for the same package ID (com.mycompany.myproject)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you can't do that.Instead you can choose paid database instead of Spark so that you can use two separate databases for the same project with same package.

Comment: right and that's what I'm doing now but lets say I want to implement facebook login in both dev and prod builds.  both require an SHA-1 Key for that but firebase prevents you from saving the same project ID AND SHA-1 key as another project.  If I was able to get another SHA-1 key then all is well.

Comment: AFAIK debug SHA-1 is same for particular firebase project no matter how many app you add in that project.

Comment: If you can create another project without using the SHA-1 key but only using the package name it should work.